# SSH issue during nix-build

Tags: git, github, ssh, nix

Error text:

```
neo@nixos ~/F/nixpkgs> nix-build -A haskellPackages.lambdabot-trusted
these derivations will be built:
  /nix/store/wf447rqgs02yxd4p1lazfzxijmyjc46h-lambdabot-139af15.drv
  /nix/store/437rz7m2hxl2p7lyla3zml8yjhs30w3k-lambdabot-trusted-5.2.drv
building '/nix/store/wf447rqgs02yxd4p1lazfzxijmyjc46h-lambdabot-139af15.drv'...
exporting git@github.com:lambdabot/lambdabot.git (rev 139af15281e815c79596ec1336b72c9ab416ba92) into /nix/store/qjb9kx6nviq2pn8v8yvyj9gypj0nhn89-lambdabot-139af15
Initialized empty Git repository in /nix/store/qjb9kx6nviq2pn8v8yvyj9gypj0nhn89-lambdabot-139af15/.git/
Could not create directory '/home/neo/.ssh'.
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Could not create directory '/home/neo/.ssh'.
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Unable to checkout 139af15281e815c79596ec1336b72c9ab416ba92 from git@github.com:lambdabot/lambdabot.git.
builder for '/nix/store/wf447rqgs02yxd4p1lazfzxijmyjc46h-lambdabot-139af15.drv' failed with exit code 1
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/437rz7m2hxl2p7lyla3zml8yjhs30w3k-lambdabot-trusted-5.2.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
error: build of '/nix/store/437rz7m2hxl2p7lyla3zml8yjhs30w3k-lambdabot-trusted-5.2.drv' failed
```

The directory `/home/neo/.ssh` exists (so this error makes no sense to me: `Could not create directory '/home/neo/.ssh'.`) and it contains the key I use to push to GitHub.

The GitHub repository it tried to connect to above is not one I own but it is public and it's only used for reading from it.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: which revision is your nixpkgs on? This works on 754763ff4ba

Comment: @JappieKerk master branch, SHA 7b20f79df38b34ae3f358938ce87759ecb47eaab

Comment: Relying on Nix builds being able to access files outside of nix store is not a good practice, because builds can be run by `nix-daemon` as a different user or in a sandbox with no access to the file system (I think the latter is your problem here).

Answer (score 1):

What worked in the end was switching from SSH to HTTP URL.